# Not able to link style.css file to front-page.php file

Tags: php, html, css

I am not able to link my style.css file to php file
I am giving the exact same path so there is no problem in path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/themeOne/style.css">**
```

this is the line

after viewing page source i get this error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title> </head><body> <h1>Not Found</h1> 
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p> </body></html>
```

can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Presumably the URL is wrong. We can't see your server or tell you what the right URL should be.

Comment: i had open it on localhost and when i viewpagesource this shows when i click on /wp-content/themes/themeOne/style.css this URL

Comment: yes we understand that. But what makes you think we can tell you where - on _your_ computer - the file actually exists (if it even exists at all)?

Comment: bro my problem is not with the file existing where my problem is that after giving the right path why its not linking

Comment: Because evidently you _didn't_ give the right path. The computer is not lying to you. Possibly it's not there, _relative to the site root_. P.S. What makes you assume I'm a "bro"? I'm not offended but I would urge you to refer to people here only with neutral terms, just using their username, in case you encounter someone who isn't a male, and doesn't like people making that assumption. Also in some cultures "bro" is starting to become a pejorative term. :-)

Comment: Ok really appreciate your answer. it was a path issue and now i know the real path. I am new to StackOverflow so don't have enough knowledge of how to communicate with others at this platform please accept my apology :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write this `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/style.css" />`